# Java polymorphism - how to call same method in different classes

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

So I'm making a game in java, and I have objects all with the 2 methods; `update()` and `render()`.

In my main class, where the game loop resides, I have to call both the `update()` and `render()` methods for every object that is updatable and renderable.
 
Is there any way to set up some form of interface where I can call the methods once and it will call it in all implemented objects?

Comment: Yes. It's called an `interface` Or an `abstract class` if you want a default implementation. Or two `interface`s with a `default` method if you use Java 8.

Comment: For clarification: do you want to be able to make a single method call which will call `#update` on every instance of an object of a class that implements that interface?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. The only issue I'm seeing so far with the other responses is that if I were to say create a class called 'World' and another class called 'Player', Both of which I want to have the update() and render() methods. If I created some 'Player' objects within the 'World' object, and then in my main 'Game' class I created a 'World' object, how would I update the 'Player' objects from within the 'Game' class with two simple method call of something like objects.update() and objects.render()?

Comment: You need to use the composite pattern. Please check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are correct, however it would be much better to use the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

```
public interface GameComponent {

    void render();

    void update();
}

public abstract class ChildComponent implements GameComponent {

    protected ContainerComponent parent; // (see below)

    // getter and setter for parent
}

public class ContainerComponent implements GameComponent {

    protected List<GameComponent> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(GameComponent child) {
        this.children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        for (GameComponent c : this.children) {
            c.update();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        for (GameComponent c : this.children) {
            c.render();
        }
    }

}
```

Then you implement your specific `GameComponent`s so that they extend either `ChildComponent` or `ContainerCompoenent`:

```
public class Player extends ChildComponent {

    @Override
    public void update() {
        // update player
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        // render player
    }

}

public class World extends ContainerComponent {

    @Override
    public void update() {
        super.update(); // update world's children (the player)
        // update the world (this can be done either after or before updating children,
        // you choose how to update your world)
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render(); // render world's children (the player)
        // render the world (this can be done either after or before rendering children,
       // you choose how to render your world)
    }

}
```

Then, in your main loop:

```
// Create player and world
Player p = new Player();
World w = new World();

// Add player to world
w.add(p);

// Update everything
w.update();

// Render everything
w.render();
```

This way, you create a *composite* of `GameComponent`s, and then you `update()` and `render()` just the topmost-level `ContainerComponent`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. I'll do some further research into this for better understanding:)

Answer (score 0):

That is **interface** are for:

```
interface I {
    void render();
}

class A implements I {
     public void render() {
         // render an A object ...
     }
}

class B implements I {
     public void render() {
         // render an B object ...
     }
}
```

and anywhere you may have

```
List<I> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new A());
list.add(new B());

for(I i:list) {
    i.render();
}
```

Objects of class A and B are diferent, but they implements the same contract (interface).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the pillars of object oriented programming, [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Basically, you need to define an interface with the methods you need. Note that in java, interface methods are public by default.

```
public interface Renderable {
  void render();
  void update();
}
```

And then you define the implementation. To implement an interface you need to use the "implements" key word. In the example below, you'll see "implements Renderable"

```
public class MyRenderable implements Renderable {
  public void render() {
     ... // method impl
  }

  public void update() {
     ... // method impl
  }
}
```

And finally, you create an instance and call the methods through the interface.

```
Renderable r = new MyRenderable();
r.render();
r.update();
```

From here you can populate a list with the type being that of your interface. You can iterate over that list, calling the methods from the interface, invoking the implementations.

Comment: Okay but what if I made another class called MySecondRenderable, which also implemented Renderable, and within the MyRenderable class I created a MySecondRenderable object. How would I call the render() and update() methods for the MySecondRenderable object from where I initialized the Renderable r = new MyRenderable()?

Comment: @Phil Please see my answer that responds exactly what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

One of the  main use of **Interface** is to achieve **polymorphism**, or the ability to perform the same operation on a number of different objects. If different objects all implement the same interface and have the same method, you can store all of those objects in a Vector/List, for example, and iterate through the Vector calling that method on each one.

As per your requirements :

```
    interface I {
    void render();
    void update();
   }

class first implements I {
     public void update(){
       // doWhaterver you want to do 
     }
     public void render() {
         // doWhaterver you want to do 
     }
}

class second implements I {
     public void update(){
       // doWhaterver you want to do 
     }
     public void render() {
         // doWhaterver you want to do 
     }
}
```

Now add them to List

```
List<I> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new first());
list.add(new second());

for(I i:list) {
    i.update();
    i.render();
}
```

it will call the implemented function ,thats called **Polymorphism**